# Deprecation warning in rails 4 for returning a hash from a #scope or #default_scope block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

so i ve a code like this written in `Rails 3.2.13` which i ve to change in `Rails 4`.

```
scope :between, lambda {|start_time, end_time|
{:conditions => ["? < starts_at < ?", Event.format_date(start_time), Event.format_date(end_time)] }}
```

I ve tried it like this but not successful..

```
scope :between, ->(starts_at, ends_at) { where(:starts_at => Event.format_date(starts_at), :ends_at => Event.format_date(ends_at)) }
```

May be i am missing something. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether this is standard code or not but this way i have done this,

```
scope :between, lambda { |starts_at, ends_at| where("? < starts_at < ?", Event.format_date(starts_at), Event.format_date(ends_at)) }
```

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Thanks